# OpenCV UMat operators

Tags: c++, opencv

With `cv::Mat` one can use `~` for `cv::bitwise_not` or `>`  to compare 2 matrices.

But [`cv::UMat`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/d45/classcv_1_1UMat.html) doesn't seem to have these operators, understandably you could simply do `cv::bitwise_not(umat,umat)` (though I've understood copying from a matrix to itself isn't very efficient, correct me if I'm wrong), but how can one compare 2 `cv::UMat` matrices, or a `cv::UMat` with a `cv::Scalar`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR use [OpenCV compare function](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#compare)

You can use `.getMat()`

```
cv::UMat A = cv::Mat(1000, 1000, CV_8UC3), B = cv::UMat(1000, 1000, CV_8UC3);
cv::randu(A, Scalar::all(0), Scalar::all(255));
cv::randu(B, Scalar::all(0), Scalar::all(255));
cv::UMat C = A.getMat(cv::ACCESS_READ) > B.getMat(cv::ACCESS_READ);
```

But this doesn't use `cv::UMat`s' hardware acceleration.

Instead you should just use [OpenCV compare function](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#compare)

```
cv::UMat A = cv::Mat(1000, 1000, CV_8UC3), B = cv::UMat(1000, 1000, CV_8UC3);
cv::randu(A, Scalar::all(0), Scalar::all(255));
cv::randu(B, Scalar::all(0), Scalar::all(255));
cv::UMat C;
cv::compare(A, B, C, CMP_GT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a very efficient answer probably, but from the top of my head...

Compare two *cv::UMat* you can convert them to a Mat and then use *cv::bitwisenot*.

Compare *cv::UMat* with *cv::Scalar*, you can convert the UMat to Mat and then use this:

```
Mat_<float> A(3,3); mf << 1,5,5,2,5,5,1,2,3;

// now use a simple MatExpr to get a mask:
Mat mask = (A == 5);

// show results:
cerr << A << endl;
cerr << mask << endl;

------------------------------

[1, 5, 5;
2, 5, 5;
1, 2, 3]
[0, 255, 255;
0, 255, 255;
0, 0, 0]
```

Depending on whether the Mat is 3,2 or 1 channel, adjust your Scalar.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: so there's no way of doing it without copying to a normal Mat then? I was hoping to make the most of the OpenCL acceleration, so i thought matrix operations would be supported

Comment: it seems that using [getMat()](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencv-30-architecture-guide-for-intel-inde-opencv) is more efficient than copying into a whole other Mat

Comment: Yeah using getMat() with the UMat is more efficient however, I haven't really used OpenCL so can't say much.